# How do you pass a json array in sequelize?

Tags: reactjs, sequelize.js

```
module.exports = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
 const tableName = sequelize.define("TableName", {
  column1: {    
     type: dataTypes.TEXT(8000),
     allowNull: false,
     defaultValues:[data_1 = '', data_2 = '']
    },
},
column2: {
 type: dataTypes:STRING(70),
 allowNull: false,
},
}),
return tableName;
};
```

I want to be able to use this to create a table named "tableName" and have 2 columns, column1 and column2. In Column 1 I want to be able to store a json array of data_1: "bs here1" and data_2: "bs here2".

For some reason this isn't working. It's probably something very simple, just can't get my head wrapped around it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = (sequelize, dataTypes) => {
 const tableName = sequelize.define("TableName", {
  column1: {    
     type: dataTypes.TEXT(8000),
     allowNull: false,
     defaultValues:'["data_1":"", "data_2":""]'
    },
},
column2: {
 type: dataTypes:STRING(70),
 allowNull: false,
},
}),
return tableName;
};
```